# JS slide and fade out tutorial

Tags: javascript, slide, fade

I'm building my website and I want to try some js animations/transitions, but for what I have in mind, I can't seem to find any usable tutorial out there.

I'm looking for simple stuff, I'm a real beginner, but I don't expect anyone to write it for me, just need some direction what tutorials I could use.
For the animation I'd like it slide from bottom to top and fade out, and for the controls I want individual text links (like home, about, contact etc). Alsoo I have a header that should not move, so the sliding parts should be divs.

I know I won't find all of this in one tutorial, but maybe I can mix 'em up to get what I want :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this Demo. http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ . Hope it will help you.Source Code : https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js